# Verification of a Function Definition in Python

Tags: python, pde, machine-learning

I want to write a function $f$ and it is defined as $f = - \nabla \cdot(|\nabla u|^{p-2} \nabla u) $ and I exact solution $u(x) = \tilde{u}(r) = 1 - \frac{p-1}{p-2} \left( s^{p/{p-1}} - (1-s)^{p/{p-1}} + 1 - \left(\frac{p}{p-1}\right)s \right)$ if $r<R$ and 0 if $r \geq R$. The following is the code block where I defined $f$ and $u$.

```
def grad_u(r, s, p):
    du_dr = np.where(r < 0.75,
                     ((p-1)/(p-2)) * ((p/(p-1))*s**(p/(p-1)-1)*(1/0.75) + (p/(p-1))*(1-s)**(p/(p-1)-1)*(1/0.75) - (p/(p-1))*(1/0.75)),
                     0)
    return du_dr

    def f_fun(input_xy, p):
        x = input_xy[:,0]
        y = input_xy[:,1]
        r = np.sqrt(np.maximum(x**2 + y**2, 1e-8))  # calculate the magnitude of the vector (x, y)
        s = r/0.75
        du_dr = grad_u(r, s, p)
        F_value = np.abs(du_dr)**(p-2) * du_dr
        # calculate the derivative of rF_value with respect to r and divide by r to get the divergence
        F = - np.divmod(np.abs(du_dr)**(p-2) * du_dr, np.maximum(r, 1e-8))[1]  # calculate f
        F[r>=0.75] = F[np.abs(r-0.75).argmin()]  # make f continuous
        return F
```

and the exact solution I defined as

```
    R = 0.75
    p = 4 # Insert your value of p here
    s = r/R
    U_exact_all = np.zeros_like(r)
    cond1 = r<R
    cond2 = r>=R
    U_exact_all[cond1] = (1 - ((p-1)/(p-2)) * (s[cond1]**(p/(p-1)) - (1-s[cond1])**(p/(p-1)) + 1 - (p/(p-1)) * s[cond1]))
    #U_exact_all[cond1] = (1 - ((p-1)/(p-2)) * (s**(p/(p-1)) - (1-s)**(p/(p-1)) + 1 - (p/(p-1)) * s))
    U_exact_all[cond2] = 0

    U_exact_boundary = U_exact_all[:num_boundary]
    U_exact_uniform = U_exact_all[num_boundary:]
```

While I am implementing it, the loss function is high. Could anyone please let me know the mistake in these two blocks?

Comment: The definition of $u(r)$ does not actually contain $r$ but depends on some variable $s$. You might want to explain what that is supposed to mean.

Comment: Separately, what have you already tried? You just say "the loss function is high", which I don't understand what that is supposed to mean (do you want to say that the difference between the expected and computed value is large?).